# Directed graph - build set of cross edges

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, pseudocode

Given a direct graph G=(V,E) what's an efficient algorithm to build the set of its cross edges and why?

P.S.: It's not homework, I'm just preparing for my DS&A final and i got stuck at this question. Thanks!

Comment: What have you found out so far? Show at least some effort.

Comment: Umm, sorry, you are right. Well, as far as I know, I could modify the BFS algorithm, so that when it meets a edge that connects 2 already visited nodes, it marks it as a cross edge, I suppose? Am I right?

Comment: It all depends on the definition of a cross edge.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find the cross edge, whose two ends are not an ancestor of each other, in a directed graph. In this case, you can modify the DFS algorithm to get the set of cross edge. Since the DFS algorithm works in a similar manner in both undirected graph and directed graph, what you need to do is record the time discovered and the time finished of one vertex and add a function that compares these value of one vertex to another vertex. For example, an arc e has two ends u and v. When checking the neighbor u of vertex v following e, if u has already been visited and is finished (i.e. u has a finished time) and the starting time of u is smaller than the starting time of v, then e is a cross edge. Once the algorithm finds the arc is a cross edge, you can just add that arc to the set of cross edges and output that set in the end.